# need to know how to move pelvis down so knee bends

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I'm trying to make a rig in such a way that when I move the pelvis down, the knees also bend with it and the top part of the body follows as well. Right now when I move the pelvis the belly stretches and the knees don't bend.

Comment: Posting a blend fine and/or more details would greatly help in being able to answer this.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying but i already figured it out, but thanks for the reply anyways :)